# Clip completely overlapping polygon(s)

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, intersection, overlapping-features

The shapefile that I'm working with (in **QGIS**) has over more than 250k polygons. But unfortunately a lot of the polygons are overlapping. The focus of my challenge is to delete or clip the polygon which entirely overlaps the smaller polygons. Below is an example. The second image(although showing poorly) is showing multiple polygons:

[image: Overlapping polygon]
[image]

What I would like is to completely alter the dataset so that only the smaller polygons are left. I've tried union and intersect, but with these functions the large overlapping polygon still remains. The union (and intersect) function provides a additional collumn with an overlapping polygon ID. Tried to delete features of which the new overlapping collumn ID with original ID is identical. So that only the overlapping parts would remain. This provides a decent result. However, not every polygon is being overlapped. So after the union and deleting identical ID's some data (polygons) is lost.

I've looked at different topics:

[Polygons which are completely overlapped by second polygon - QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304506/polygons-which-are-completely-overlapped-by-second-polygon-qgis)

[Clipping with multiple overlapping polygons while maintaining unique IDs and overlap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144721/clipping-with-multiple-overlapping-polygons-while-maintaining-unique-ids-and-ove)

The last topic seems to partly have the answer, but in my case the large overlapping polygon still remains.

The result should either be to delete the completely overlapping polygon, or to clip (by using intersect or not) all the polygons by other overlapping polygons. It doesn't matter if this results in various small polygons. Working in the environment of R is also not problem.

WKT's (EPSG: 28992):

```
1 <- MultiPolygon (((102183.036 448132.8, 102177.325 448140.399,
        102163.121 448159.698, 102163.237 448160.366, 102163.635 448162.656, 102165.83 448165.264, 102167.45 448166.34, 102185.034 448172.226, 102189.672 448173.189, 102198.273 448173.284, 102221.27 448173.92, 102244.522 448174.672, 102264.265 448175.706, 102286.742 448176.706, 102298.77 448178.139, 102310.062 448179.127, 102331.795 448180.662, 102337.509 448180.348, 102346.192 448176.44, 102351.414 448174.578, 102360.761 448175.216, 102395.437 448177.221, 102418.163 448179.431, 102460.607 448180.134, 102540.184 448180.9, 102592.352 448181.191, 102702.776 448183.054, 103229.694 448189.444, 103230.81 448189.451, 103250.931 448189.549, 103256.323 448190.27, 103258.3 448190.768, 103259.342 448191.339, 103259.965 448192.361, 103260.288 448193.909, 103260.196 448194.877, 103259.682 448195.696, 103258.388 448196.783, 103257.581 448197.081, 103256.142 448197.292, 103224.383 448197.04, 103192.275 448196.56, 103129.356 448195.945, 103098.124 448195.935, 103064.384 448195.209, 103043.242 448194.906, 103042.963 448195.159, 103042.732 448195.456, 103042.553 448195.788, 103042.434 448196.145, 103042.376 448196.517, 103042.383 448196.893, 103042.453 448197.263, 103042.585 448197.616, 103042.775 448197.941, 103043.016 448198.23, 103043.304 448198.473, 103043.628 448198.664, 103053.597 448198.912, 103080.509 448199.454, 103110.401 448199.549, 103167.012 448200.5, 103194.78 448200.576, 103223.669 448200.947, 103252.084 448201.151, 103257.761 448201.032, 103258.809 448201.861, 103259.89 448203.188, 103260.004 448204.836, 103260.197 448205.865, 103260.368 448207.538, 103260.352 448210.45, 103260.29 448211.723, 103265.452 448211.78, 103265.487 448210.468, 103265.548 448207.609, 103266.44 448207.601, 103266.343 448203.077, 103267.024 448201.756, 103268.567 448200.946, 103278.327 448200.961, 103302.678 448201.638, 103321.144 448201.67, 103326.674 448201.793, 103326.736 448200.223, 103325.823 448199.698, 103317.619 448199.427, 103295.975 448199.242, 103293.568 448199.059, 103267.961 448199.368, 103267.235 448199.189, 103266.107 448197.682, 103265.882 448195.663, 103266.357 448194.423, 103266.913 448193.314, 103267.945 448192.438, 103274.845 448191.802, 103292.374 448191.694, 103339.932 448192.69, 103365.144 448192.386, 103386.138 448193.705, 103459.659 448196.036, 103525.06 448197.794, 103567.889 448199.438, 103632.253 448204.942, 103665.097 448206.411, 103669.373 448206.249, 103670.994 448206.071, 103672.242 448205.685, 103674.865 448204.217, 103678.095 448202.302, 103681.341 448201.101, 103684.103 448200.54, 103697.45 448199.912, 103701.599 448199.817, 103703.773 448199.638, 103705.487 448199.23, 103707.179 448198.347, 103709.277 448196.674, 103718.772 448187.478, 103722.93 448184.62, 103725.341 448182.129, 103725.438 448181.977, 103725.509 448181.811, 103725.553 448181.635, 103725.568 448181.455, 103725.554 448181.275, 103725.512 448181.1, 103725.442 448180.933, 103725.346 448180.78, 103723.01 448176.469, 103722.918 448176.162, 103722.879 448175.843, 103722.893 448175.522, 103722.961 448175.208, 103723.08 448174.91, 103723.248 448174.636, 103723.458 448174.394, 103893.349 448004.607, 103894.02 448003.216, 103870.199 447978.871, 103728.513 448121.781, 103677.664 448173.03, 103655.69 448194.829, 103653.74 448196.472, 103651.54 448197.761, 103649.154 448198.661, 103646.65 448199.145, 103631.477 448198.917, 103533.797 448193.061, 103464.375 448190.348, 103430.338 448157.352, 103418.15 448166.348, 103411.266 448173.746, 103409.97 448174.594, 103401.15 448174.519, 103400.121 448173.944, 103394.863 448169.325, 103392.997 448165.245, 103393.193 448156.224, 103383.263 448146.162, 103382.55 448145.162, 103382.061 448143.268, 103382.564 448141.512, 103383.889 448139.593, 103389.661 448132.84, 103381.358 448124.638, 103381.186 448124.329, 103373.251 448116.629, 103362.855 448125.035, 103360.422 448125.653, 103358.541 448124.94, 103351.621 448118.578, 103349.28 448118.236, 103346.155 448120.801, 103283.07 448184.311, 103229.764 448184.043, 102703.347 448178.071, 102606.507 448176.806, 102543.702 448176.117, 102451.076 448174.954, 102411.037 448174.045, 102362.3 448170.29, 102359.03 448169.749, 102353.208 448168.631, 102351.499 448168.35, 102349.843 448167.843, 102348.269 448167.12, 102346.806 448166.193, 102339.59 448160.974, 102337.392 448159.594, 102328.626 448155.401, 102323.9 448153.645, 102319.076 448152.178, 102313.177 448150.282, 102308.193 448148.87, 102304.1 448148.56, 102304.089 448149.512, 102254.181 448149.647, 102216.235 448149.894, 102200.706 448149.363, 102193.009 448148.582, 102182.12 448146.622, 102181.511 448146.318, 102180.961 448145.917, 102180.486 448145.429, 102180.099 448144.868, 102179.812 448144.251, 102179.632 448143.594, 102179.682 448142.059, 102179.935 448140.548, 102180.519 448138.714, 102181.397 448137.004, 102184.042 448133.657, 102183.834 448133.485, 102183.036 448132.8),(102323.02 448154.569, 102322.095 448154.261, 102322.386 448153.338, 102323.304 448153.626, 102323.02 448154.569),(103325.998 448141.413, 103326.722 448142.074, 103326.001 448142.775, 103325.316 448142.097, 103325.998 448141.413)))
    2 <- MultiPolygon (((102184.042 448133.657, 102183.834 448133.485, 102183.036 448132.8, 102177.325 448140.399, 102163.121 448159.698, 102163.237 448160.366, 102163.635 448162.656, 102165.83 448165.264, 102167.45 448166.34, 102185.034 448172.226, 102189.672 448173.189, 102198.273 448173.284, 102221.27 448173.92, 102244.522 448174.672, 102264.265 448175.706, 102286.742 448176.706, 102298.77 448178.139, 102310.062 448179.127, 102331.795 448180.662, 102337.509 448180.348, 102346.192 448176.44, 102351.414 448174.578, 102360.761 448175.216, 102395.437 448177.221, 102418.163 448179.431, 102460.607 448180.134, 102540.184 448180.9, 102592.352 448181.191, 102702.776 448183.054, 103229.694 448189.444, 103230.81 448189.451, 103250.931 448189.549, 103256.323 448190.27, 103258.3 448190.768, 103259.342 448191.339, 103259.965 448192.361, 103260.288 448193.909, 103260.196 448194.877, 103259.682 448195.696, 103258.388 448196.783, 103257.581 448197.081, 103256.142 448197.292, 103224.383 448197.04, 103192.275 448196.56, 103129.356 448195.945, 103098.124 448195.935, 103064.384 448195.209, 103043.242 448194.906, 103042.963 448195.159, 103042.732 448195.456, 103042.553 448195.788, 103042.434 448196.145, 103042.376 448196.517, 103042.383 448196.893, 103042.453 448197.263, 103042.585 448197.616, 103042.775 448197.941, 103043.016 448198.23, 103043.304 448198.473, 103043.628 448198.664, 103053.597 448198.912, 103080.509 448199.454, 103110.401 448199.549, 103167.012 448200.5, 103194.78 448200.576, 103223.669 448200.947, 103252.084 448201.151, 103257.761 448201.032, 103258.809 448201.861, 103259.89 448203.188, 103260.004 448204.836, 103260.197 448205.865, 103260.368 448207.538, 103260.352 448210.45, 103260.29 448211.723, 103265.452 448211.78, 103265.487 448210.468, 103265.548 448207.609, 103266.44 448207.601, 103266.343 448203.077, 103267.024 448201.756, 103268.567 448200.946, 103278.327 448200.961, 103302.678 448201.638, 103321.144 448201.67, 103326.674 448201.793, 103326.736 448200.223, 103325.823 448199.698, 103317.619 448199.427, 103295.975 448199.242, 103293.568 448199.059, 103267.961 448199.368, 103267.235 448199.189, 103266.107 448197.682, 103265.882 448195.663, 103266.357 448194.423, 103266.913 448193.314, 103267.945 448192.438, 103274.845 448191.802, 103292.374 448191.694, 103339.932 448192.69, 103365.144 448192.386, 103386.138 448193.705, 103459.659 448196.036, 103525.06 448197.794, 103558.199 448199.938, 103632.253 448204.942, 103644.229 448205.687, 103649.432 448206.898, 103664.951 448206.925, 103668.685 448206.442, 103674.865 448204.217, 103682.06 448202.43, 103701.599 448199.817, 103709.277 448196.674, 103714.083 448193.149, 103722.93 448184.62, 103725.291 448181.787, 103724.94256455 448181.3442284, 103724.62459897 448180.87909202, 103724.33853416 448180.39368407, 103724.08565745 448179.89018896, 103723.86710684 448179.3708725, 103723.68386583 448178.8380717, 103723.53675905 448178.29418425, 103723.42644849 448177.74165775, 103723.35343058 448177.18297864, 103723.31803391 448176.62066109, 103723.32041777 448176.05723561, 103723.36057143 448175.49523771, 103723.43831418 448174.93719647, 103723.55329619 448174.38562318, 103723.705 448173.843, 103734.358 448163.878, 103762.006 448135.147, 103770.864 448127.017, 103883.216 448014.733, 103888.994 448008.728, 103889.15556651 448008.55778444, 103889.30528416 448008.37705895, 103889.44247105 448008.18664667, 103889.56650234 448007.98741485, 103889.67681313 448007.78027092, 103889.77290098 448007.56615834, 103889.85432827 448007.34605227, 103889.92072412 448007.12095526, 103889.97178612 448006.89189249, 103890.00728171 448006.65990728, 103890.02704921 448006.42605621, 103890.03099861 448006.19140439, 103890.0191119 448005.95702054, 103889.99144323 448005.72397222, 103889.94811862 448005.49332084, 103889.88933539 448005.26611695, 103889.81536128 448005.04339536, 103889.72653321 448004.82617047, 103889.62325576 448004.61543167, 103889.5059993 448004.41213876, 103889.37529791 448004.21721769, 103889.23174687 448004.03155623, 103889.076 448003.856, 103868.862 447983.545, 103868.76043367 447983.42500475, 103868.65115703 447983.31198619, 103868.53464815 447983.20643875, 103868.41141675 447983.10882419, 103868.28200193 447983.01956959, 103868.14696988 447982.93906538, 103868.00691135 447982.8676638, 103867.86243907 447982.80567719, 103867.71418509 447982.75337674, 103867.56279799 447982.71099128, 103867.40894008 447982.67870621, 103867.25328448 447982.65666279, 103867.09651214 447982.64495745, 103866.93930893 447982.64364141, 103866.7823626 447982.65272042, 103866.62635976 447982.67215477, 103866.4719829 447982.70185941, 103866.31990741 447982.74170442, 103866.17079859 447982.79151547, 103866.02530877 447982.85107464, 103865.88407446 447982.92012136, 103865.74771354 447982.99835356, 103865.61682256 447983.085429, 103865.49197416 447983.18096673, 103865.37371454 447983.28454877, 103865.26256105 447983.395722, 103865.159 447983.514, 103772.273 448077.039, 103724.844 448124.578, 103657.657 448192.316, 103653.74 448196.472, 103651.54 448197.761, 103649.154 448198.661, 103646.65 448199.145, 103631.477 448198.917, 103533.797 448193.061, 103464.375 448190.348, 103430.338 448157.352, 103418.15 448166.348, 103411.266 448173.746, 103409.97 448174.594, 103401.15 448174.519, 103400.121 448173.944, 103394.863 448169.325, 103392.997 448165.245, 103393.193 448156.224, 103391.479 448154.183, 103389.071 448151.119, 103385.034 448147.263, 103384.74628272 448146.98514427, 103384.47735843 448146.68906193, 103384.22837919 448146.37602141, 103384.00041165 448146.04736379, 103383.79443245 448145.70449704, 103383.611324 448145.34889005, 103383.45187076 448144.98206626, 103383.31675583 448144.60559715, 103383.20655805 448144.22109555, 103383.12174952 448143.83020867, 103383.06269356 448143.43461111, 103383.02964317 448143.03599764, 103383.02273995 448142.63607591, 103383.04201346 448142.23655926, 103383.08738113 448141.83915919, 103383.15864861 448141.44557823, 103383.25551058 448141.05750246, 103383.37755209 448140.67659447, 103383.52425029 448140.30448604, 103383.69497673 448139.94277135, 103383.889 448139.593, 103389.661 448132.84, 103381.358 448124.638, 103381.186 448124.329, 103373.251 448116.629, 103362.855 448125.035, 103360.422 448125.653, 103358.541 448124.94, 103351.621 448118.578, 103349.28 448118.236, 103346.155 448120.801, 103283.07 448184.311, 103229.764 448184.043, 102703.347 448178.071, 102606.507 448176.806, 102543.702 448176.117, 102451.076 448174.954, 102411.037 448174.045, 102362.3 448170.29, 102359.03 448169.749, 102353.208 448168.631, 102351.499 448168.35, 102349.843 448167.843, 102348.269 448167.12, 102346.806 448166.193, 102339.59 448160.974, 102337.392 448159.594, 102328.626 448155.401, 102323.9 448153.645, 102319.076 448152.178, 102313.177 448150.282, 102308.193 448148.87, 102304.1 448148.56, 102304.089 448149.512, 102254.181 448149.647, 102216.235 448149.894, 102200.706 448149.363, 102193.009 448148.582, 102182.12 448146.622, 102181.511 448146.318, 102180.961 448145.917, 102180.486 448145.429, 102180.099 448144.868, 102179.812 448144.251, 102179.632 448143.594, 102179.682 448142.059, 102179.935 448140.548, 102180.519 448138.714, 102181.397 448137.004, 102184.042 448133.657),(103326.001 448142.775, 103325.316 448142.097, 103325.998 448141.413, 103326.722 448142.074, 103326.001 448142.775),(102323.02 448154.569, 102322.095 448154.261, 102322.386 448153.338, 102323.304 448153.626, 102323.02 448154.569)))
    3 <- MultiPolygon (((102349.048 448167.478, 102348.45 448175.635, 102351.414 448174.578, 102360.761 448175.216, 102395.437 448177.221, 102418.163 448179.431, 102460.607 448180.134, 102540.184 448180.9, 102592.352 448181.191, 102702.776 448183.054, 103229.694 448189.444, 103230.81 448189.451, 103250.931 448189.549, 103256.323 448190.27, 103258.3 448190.768, 103259.342 448191.339, 103259.965 448192.361, 103260.288 448193.909, 103260.196 448194.877, 103259.682 448195.696, 103258.388 448196.783, 103257.581 448197.081, 103256.142 448197.292, 103224.383 448197.04, 103192.275 448196.56, 103129.356 448195.945, 103098.124 448195.935, 103064.384 448195.209, 103043.242 448194.906, 103042.963 448195.159, 103042.732 448195.456, 103042.553 448195.788, 103042.434 448196.145, 103042.376 448196.517, 103042.383 448196.893, 103042.453 448197.263, 103042.585 448197.616, 103042.775 448197.941, 103043.016 448198.23, 103043.304 448198.473, 103043.628 448198.664, 103053.597 448198.912, 103080.509 448199.454, 103110.401 448199.549, 103167.012 448200.5, 103194.78 448200.576, 103223.669 448200.947, 103252.084 448201.151, 103257.761 448201.032, 103258.809 448201.861, 103259.89 448203.188, 103260.004 448204.836, 103260.197 448205.865, 103260.368 448207.538, 103260.352 448210.45, 103260.29 448211.723, 103265.452 448211.78, 103265.487 448210.468, 103265.548 448207.609, 103266.44 448207.601, 103266.343 448203.077, 103267.024 448201.756, 103268.567 448200.946, 103278.327 448200.961, 103302.678 448201.638, 103321.144 448201.67, 103326.674 448201.793, 103326.736 448200.223, 103325.823 448199.698, 103317.619 448199.427, 103295.975 448199.242, 103293.568 448199.059, 103267.961 448199.368, 103267.235 448199.189, 103266.107 448197.682, 103265.882 448195.663, 103266.357 448194.423, 103266.913 448193.314, 103267.945 448192.438, 103274.845 448191.802, 103292.374 448191.694, 103339.932 448192.69, 103365.144 448192.386, 103386.138 448193.705, 103459.659 448196.036, 103525.06 448197.794, 103558.199 448199.938, 103632.253 448204.942, 103644.229 448205.687, 103649.432 448206.898, 103664.951 448206.925, 103668.685 448206.442, 103674.865 448204.217, 103682.06 448202.43, 103701.599 448199.817, 103709.277 448196.674, 103714.083 448193.149, 103722.93 448184.62, 103725.291 448181.787, 103724.94256455 448181.3442284, 103724.62459897 448180.87909202, 103724.33853416 448180.39368407, 103724.08565745 448179.89018896, 103723.86710684 448179.3708725, 103723.68386583 448178.8380717, 103723.53675905 448178.29418425, 103723.42644849 448177.74165775, 103723.35343058 448177.18297864, 103723.31803391 448176.62066109, 103723.32041777 448176.05723561, 103723.36057143 448175.49523771, 103723.43831418 448174.93719647, 103723.55329619 448174.38562318, 103723.705 448173.843, 103734.358 448163.878, 103762.006 448135.147, 103770.864 448127.017, 103883.216 448014.733, 103888.994 448008.728, 103889.15556651 448008.55778444, 103889.30528416 448008.37705895, 103889.44247105 448008.18664667, 103889.56650234 448007.98741485, 103889.67681313 448007.78027092, 103889.77290098 448007.56615834, 103889.85432827 448007.34605227, 103889.92072412 448007.12095526, 103889.97178612 448006.89189249, 103890.00728171 448006.65990728, 103890.02704921 448006.42605621, 103890.03099861 448006.19140439, 103890.0191119 448005.95702054, 103889.99144323 448005.72397222, 103889.94811862 448005.49332084, 103889.88933539 448005.26611695, 103889.81536128 448005.04339536, 103889.72653321 448004.82617047, 103889.62325576 448004.61543167, 103889.5059993 448004.41213876, 103889.37529791 448004.21721769, 103889.23174687 448004.03155623, 103889.076 448003.856, 103868.862 447983.545, 103868.76043367 447983.42500475, 103868.65115703 447983.31198619, 103868.53464815 447983.20643875, 103868.41141675 447983.10882419, 103868.28200193 447983.01956959, 103868.14696988 447982.93906538, 103868.00691135 447982.8676638, 103867.86243907 447982.80567719, 103867.71418509 447982.75337674, 103867.56279799 447982.71099128, 103867.40894008 447982.67870621, 103867.25328448 447982.65666279, 103867.09651214 447982.64495745, 103866.93930893 447982.64364141, 103866.7823626 447982.65272042, 103866.62635976 447982.67215477, 103866.4719829 447982.70185941, 103866.31990741 447982.74170442, 103866.17079859 447982.79151547, 103866.02530877 447982.85107464, 103865.88407446 447982.92012136, 103865.74771354 447982.99835356, 103865.61682256 447983.085429, 103865.49197416 447983.18096673, 103865.37371454 447983.28454877, 103865.26256105 447983.395722, 103865.159 447983.514, 103772.273 448077.039, 103724.844 448124.578, 103657.657 448192.316, 103653.74 448196.472, 103651.54 448197.761, 103649.154 448198.661, 103646.65 448199.145, 103631.477 448198.917, 103533.797 448193.061, 103464.375 448190.348, 103430.338 448157.352, 103418.15 448166.348, 103411.266 448173.746, 103409.97 448174.594, 103401.15 448174.519, 103400.121 448173.944, 103394.863 448169.325, 103392.997 448165.245, 103393.193 448156.224, 103391.479 448154.183, 103389.071 448151.119, 103385.034 448147.263, 103384.74628272 448146.98514427, 103384.47735843 448146.68906193, 103384.22837919 448146.37602141, 103384.00041165 448146.04736379, 103383.79443245 448145.70449704, 103383.611324 448145.34889005, 103383.45187076 448144.98206626, 103383.31675583 448144.60559715, 103383.20655805 448144.22109555, 103383.12174952 448143.83020867, 103383.06269356 448143.43461111, 103383.02964317 448143.03599764, 103383.02273995 448142.63607591, 103383.04201346 448142.23655926, 103383.08738113 448141.83915919, 103383.15864861 448141.44557823, 103383.25551058 448141.05750246, 103383.37755209 448140.67659447, 103383.52425029 448140.30448604, 103383.69497673 448139.94277135, 103383.889 448139.593, 103389.661 448132.84, 103381.358 448124.638, 103381.186 448124.329, 103373.251 448116.629, 103362.855 448125.035, 103360.422 448125.653, 103358.541 448124.94, 103351.621 448118.578, 103349.28 448118.236, 103346.155 448120.801, 103283.07 448184.311, 103229.764 448184.043, 102703.347 448178.071, 102606.507 448176.806, 102543.702 448176.117, 102451.076 448174.954, 102411.037 448174.045, 102362.3 448170.29, 102359.03 448169.749, 102353.208 448168.631, 102351.499 448168.35, 102349.843 448167.843, 102349.048 448167.478),(103325.316 448142.097, 103325.998 448141.413, 103326.722 448142.074, 103326.001 448142.775, 103325.316 448142.097)))
    4 <- MultiPolygon (((103260.196 448194.877, 103259.682 448195.696, 103258.388 448196.783, 103257.581 448197.081, 103256.142 448197.292, 103224.383 448197.04, 103192.275 448196.56, 103129.356 448195.945, 103098.124 448195.935, 103064.384 448195.209, 103043.242 448194.906, 103042.963 448195.159, 103042.732 448195.456, 103042.553 448195.788, 103042.434 448196.145, 103042.376 448196.517, 103042.383 448196.893, 103042.453 448197.263, 103042.585 448197.616, 103042.775 448197.941, 103043.016 448198.23, 103043.304 448198.473, 103043.628 448198.664, 103053.597 448198.912, 103080.509 448199.454, 103110.401 448199.549, 103167.012 448200.5, 103194.78 448200.576, 103223.669 448200.947, 103252.084 448201.151, 103257.761 448201.032, 103258.809 448201.861, 103259.89 448203.188, 103260.196 448194.877)))
    5 <- MultiPolygon (((103266.44 448207.601, 103266.343 448203.077, 103267.024 448201.756, 103268.567 448200.946, 103278.327 448200.961, 103302.678 448201.638, 103321.144 448201.67, 103326.674 448201.793, 103326.736 448200.223, 103325.823 448199.698, 103317.619 448199.427, 103295.975 448199.242, 103293.568 448199.059, 103267.961 448199.368, 103267.235 448199.189, 103266.107 448197.682, 103265.882 448195.663, 103266.357 448194.423, 103266.913 448193.314, 103267.945 448192.438, 103296.856 448189.773, 103352.351 448190.253, 103456.89 448194.045, 103530.568 448196.247, 103632.253 448204.942, 103681.376 448207.139, 103692.284 448205.744, 103703.306 448203.343, 103704.482 448202.937, 103705.576 448202.345, 103706.558 448201.581, 103707.402 448200.666, 103725.341 448182.129, 103725.438 448181.977, 103725.509 448181.811, 103725.553 448181.635, 103725.568 448181.455, 103725.554 448181.275, 103725.512 448181.1, 103725.442 448180.933, 103725.346 448180.78, 103723.01 448176.469, 103722.918 448176.162, 103722.879 448175.843, 103722.893 448175.522, 103722.961 448175.208, 103723.08 448174.91, 103723.248 448174.636, 103723.458 448174.394, 103893.349 448004.607, 103894.02 448003.216, 103870.199 447978.871, 103728.513 448121.781, 103677.664 448173.03, 103655.69 448194.829, 103653.74 448196.472, 103651.54 448197.761, 103649.154 448198.661, 103646.65 448199.145, 103631.477 448198.917, 103533.797 448193.061, 103464.375 448190.348, 103430.338 448157.352, 103418.15 448166.348, 103411.266 448173.746, 103409.97 448174.594, 103401.15 448174.519, 103400.121 448173.944, 103394.863 448169.325, 103392.997 448165.245, 103393.193 448156.224, 103383.263 448146.162, 103382.55 448145.162, 103382.061 448143.268, 103382.564 448141.512, 103383.889 448139.593, 103389.661 448132.84, 103381.358 448124.638, 103381.186 448124.329, 103373.251 448116.629, 103362.855 448125.035, 103360.422 448125.653, 103358.541 448124.94, 103351.621 448118.578, 103349.28 448118.236, 103346.155 448120.801, 103283.07 448184.311, 103229.764 448184.043, 102703.347 448178.071, 102606.507 448176.806, 102543.702 448176.117, 102451.076 448174.954, 102411.037 448174.045, 102362.3 448170.29, 102359.03 448169.749, 102353.208 448168.631, 102351.499 448168.35, 102349.843 448167.843, 102348.269 448167.12, 102346.806 448166.193, 102339.59 448160.974, 102337.392 448159.594, 102328.626 448155.401, 102323.9 448153.645, 102319.076 448152.178, 102313.177 448150.282, 102308.193 448148.87, 102304.1 448148.56, 102304.089 448149.512, 102254.181 448149.647, 102216.235 448149.894, 102200.706 448149.363, 102193.009 448148.582, 102182.12 448146.622, 102181.511 448146.318, 102180.961 448145.917, 102180.486 448145.429, 102180.099 448144.868, 102179.812 448144.251, 102179.632 448143.594, 102179.682 448142.059, 102179.935 448140.548, 102180.519 448138.714, 102181.397 448137.004, 102184.042 448133.657, 102183.834 448133.485, 102183.036 448132.8, 102177.325 448140.399, 102163.121 448159.698, 102163.237 448160.366, 102163.635 448162.656, 102165.83 448165.264, 102167.45 448166.34, 102185.034 448172.226, 102189.672 448173.189, 102198.273 448173.284, 102221.27 448173.92, 102244.522 448174.672, 102264.265 448175.706, 102286.742 448176.706, 102298.77 448178.139, 102310.062 448179.127, 102331.795 448180.662, 102337.509 448180.348, 102346.192 448176.44, 102351.414 448174.578, 102360.761 448175.216, 102395.437 448177.221, 102418.163 448179.431, 102460.607 448180.134, 102540.184 448180.9, 102592.352 448181.191, 102702.776 448183.054, 103229.694 448189.444, 103230.81 448189.451, 103250.931 448189.549, 103256.323 448190.27, 103258.3 448190.768, 103259.342 448191.339, 103259.965 448192.361, 103260.288 448193.909, 103260.196 448194.877, 103259.682 448195.696, 103258.388 448196.783, 103257.581 448197.081, 103256.142 448197.292, 103224.383 448197.04, 103192.275 448196.56, 103129.356 448195.945, 103098.124 448195.935, 103064.384 448195.209, 103043.242 448194.906, 103042.963 448195.159, 103042.732 448195.456, 103042.553 448195.788, 103042.434 448196.145, 103042.376 448196.517, 103042.383 448196.893, 103042.453 448197.263, 103042.585 448197.616, 103042.775 448197.941, 103043.016 448198.23, 103043.304 448198.473, 103043.628 448198.664, 103053.597 448198.912, 103080.509 448199.454, 103110.401 448199.549, 103167.012 448200.5, 103194.78 448200.576, 103223.669 448200.947, 103252.084 448201.151, 103257.761 448201.032, 103258.809 448201.861, 103259.89 448203.188, 103260.004 448204.836, 103260.197 448205.865, 103260.368 448207.538, 103260.352 448210.45, 103260.29 448211.723, 103265.452 448211.78, 103265.487 448210.468, 103265.548 448207.609, 103266.44 448207.601),(103325.998 448141.413, 103326.722 448142.074, 103326.001 448142.775, 103325.316 448142.097, 103325.998 448141.413),(102323.02 448154.569, 102322.095 448154.261, 102322.386 448153.338, 102323.304 448153.626, 102323.02 448154.569)))
    6 <- MultiPolygon (((103283.101 448191.751, 103283.07 448184.311, 103229.764 448184.043, 102703.347 448178.071, 102606.507 448176.806, 102543.702 448176.117, 102451.076 448174.954, 102411.037 448174.045, 102362.3 448170.29, 102359.03 448169.749, 102353.208 448168.631, 102351.499 448168.35, 102349.843 448167.843, 102349.048 448167.478, 102348.45 448175.635, 102351.414 448174.578, 102360.761 448175.216, 102395.437 448177.221, 102418.163 448179.431, 102460.607 448180.134, 102540.184 448180.9, 102592.352 448181.191, 102702.776 448183.054, 103229.694 448189.444, 103230.81 448189.451, 103250.931 448189.549, 103256.323 448190.27, 103258.3 448190.768, 103267.945 448192.438, 103274.845 448191.802, 103283.101 448191.751)))
```